# why can't python see my module?

Tags: python, import

I have a file structure like this:

```
/package/main.py
/package/__init__.py
/package/config_files/config.py
/package/config_files/__init__.py
```

I'm trying to dynamically import `config.py` from `main.py` based on a command line argument, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from importlib import import_module

cmd_arguments = sys.argv
config_str = cmd_arguments[1]    
config = import_module(config_str, 'config_files')
```

but it complains breaks with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'default_config'`.  Similar code in ipython does not suffer the same issue, when  called from `/package`

If there is a better way to load a package at run time via user input, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What is your `sys.path` and is the directory that contains `default_config` in there?

Comment: Can you include the working directory and the directory that contain the `config_files`? Also, is there a `__init__.py` on the config_files dir?

Comment: Your nested package name is `package.config_files`, not `config_files`.

Comment: Are you running the `main.py` file as the script? Then you are breaking the expectations of `package` being a proper top-level package. Put scripts **outside** of the package or use `python -m package.main` to run a nested module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my end goal is portable code that I can run as `main config` from the command line.  Is this a good case to move `main` outside the package?

Comment: It’s a good case to have a separate file be the script. Usually, you have setuptools generate that file from your `setup.py`. That file can then import `package.main` and run functions defined there.

Comment: Yes, provided you have a script outside the package. See the [Flask `setup.py` file](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/setup.py) for a concrete example. Look for the `console_scripts` entry. Then at the [`flask.cli` module](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/cli.py) where the `main()` function will be called from a generated script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to import from a nested package, so use the full package name:

```
config = import_module(config_str, 'package.config_files')
```

Alternatively, use a relative import, and set the second argument to `package`:

```
config = import_module('.config_files.{}'.format(config_str), 'package')
```

This is more secure, as now the `config_str` string can't be used to 'break out' of the `config_files` sub package.

You do want to strip dots from user-provided names (and, preferably, limit the name to valid Python identifiers only).